# Makefile Rules and If Statements -- How?

Tags: unix, if-statement, makefile, tcsh

I'm new to Makefiles so please bear with me.

I need to modify a Makefile so some rules call different utilities depending on a variable.

Right now, a rule looks like:

```
ci:
    [shell syntax for tool (A)]
```

But now I need ci to have a different syntax depending on the variable. So I define a global variable at the top of the file:

```
TOOL = toolA
```

or

```
TOOL = toolB
```

Ideally what I'd like is something like this, but **obviously it doesn't work**:

```
ifeq ($TOOL, toolA)
    ci:
        [syntax for tool (A)]
else
    ci:
        [syntax for tool (B)
endif
```

Does anyone know the best way to implement something like this properly?

Thanks!!

**EDIT**: The tool syntax is more complicated than one line. Sometimes its multiple lines and not just "toolA args etc etc". Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Consider implementing a tool-neutral (shell?) script that gets told (by argument or other means) what to do, and use that unconditionally.

Comment: That's what I thought of at first, but I wanted to do this without bringing in outside scripts. Might have to resort to that if I can't get this to work. Thanks though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just missing some parentheses:

```
ifeq ($(TOOL), toolA)
...
```

**P.S.** You can make the conditional a little tighter (and remove a little redundancy):

```
ci:
ifeq ($(TOOL), toolA)
    [syntax for tool (A)]
else
    [syntax for tool (B)
endif
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I wasn't that far off!

But now I'm having problems with the if statement--but I'll create a new question for that. Thanks!

Comment: @Yasky: this *is* comparing strings. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to compare a string which is an output from `uname`. I resorted to writing a mini shell script in the Makefile though

Comment: @Yasky: I'm not sure what you mean, but if you post it as a question I'm sure someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you do that with a macro:

```
  # put tool A or tool B command line here
  TOOL=...

  ci:
       $(TOOL) args
```

That can be extended with something like a `TOOLARGS` macro, so something like

```
  ci:
       $(TOOL) $(TOOLARGS)
```

Then you can modify the makefile, or put the macros on the command line

```
  $ make TOOL=... TOOLARGS=...
```

If you want to encapsulate it, you could use an if to set the arguments.

Comment: That would work! But like with @mark4o's answer, the "tool syntax" above is more complicated than just one line...it needs several, and sometimes it's not just "toolA". I should have been more clear in my original post. Sorry about that. Thanks though!

Comment: @RaytheonLiszt: the more complex the commands, the more merit there is to using a script to cover up the complexity.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: very true. I think if I hit one more roadblock, I'm just going to go your way and use a script. =(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TOOLARGS_toolA = -a1 -a2
TOOLARGS_toolB = -b1 -b2

ci:
        $(TOOL) $(TOOLARGS_$(TOOL))
```

Now if `TOOL` is `toolA` it will use the args `-a1 -a2`, and if `TOOL` is `toolB` then it will use the args `-b1 -b2`.

Comment: That is nice! But unfortunately the "tool syntax" above is more complicated than just one line...it needs several, and sometimes it's not just "toolA". I should ahve been more clear in my original post, sorry. Thanks though!