# Makefile if-statement not evaluating with export variables?

Tags: unix, if-statement, makefile, global-variables

This is an offshoot to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348643/makefile-rules-and-if-statements-how).

Is there something special I have to do in order to make this work with export variables?

So I'm running this off of a Makefile that includes a master Makefile in another location. In this local Makefile, I have:

```
include /path/to/master/Makefile/
export TOOL = A
```

Now in my Master Makefile I have:

```
ifeq ( $(TOOL), A )
    echo "Tool A will be run..."
    [syntax for toolA]
else
    echo "Tool B will be run..."
    [syntax for toolB]
endif
```

But when I run gmake, toolB is always run! I checked the variable $(TOOL) and it shows A. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

**EDIT**: Adding Makefile example.

For my problem, moving the include to *after* the export fixed my problem. But this is an existing Makefile, and having the include at the very top has always worked!

The include statement is up top in the local, and all the exports at the bottom. Only my new export line fails. Does anyone know why?

***Local Makefile***

```
export TOOL A
include /path/to/master/Makefile
export VERSION IMP-IR5
```

***Master Makefile***

```
export VERSION IAP-100

ci:
ifeq ( $(TOOL), A )
    echo "Tool A will be run..."
    [syntax for toolA]
    echo $(VERSION)
else
    echo "Tool B will be run..."
    [syntax for toolB]
    echo $(VERSION)
endif
```

***Output***

```
echo "Tool A will be run..."
Tool A will be run...
echo IMP-IR5
IMP-IR5
```

But if I switch the top to lines in the local Makefile (like it was originally):

```
include /path/to/master/Makefile
export TOOL A
export VERSION IMP-IR5
```

I get:

```
echo "Tool B will be run..."
Tool B will be run...
echo IMP-IR5
IMP-IR5
```

Why does IMP-IR5 go through but not tool A? So confused...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving your `export TOOL = A` line above the `include` statement in your local Makefile. Also change `ifeq ( $(TOOL), A )` to `ifeq ($(TOOL),A)`.

Answer (score 2):

Put the variable definition before the include statement:

```
export TOOL = A
include /path/to/master/Makefile/
```

otherwise the rule in the included Makefile won't see it.

Also, be careful of whitespace in your conditional:

```
ifeq ($(TOOL),A)
```

**EDIT:**

Easy! You are using the two variables differently. Make evaluates the makefile from top to bottom, decides which targets to rebuild before rebuilding any of them, *then* executes the rules, using whatever values the variables have acquired. Consider this makefile:

```
# I've added '@' to make it quieter.
ci:
ifeq ( $(TOOL), A )
    @echo "Tool A will be run..."
    @echo $(VERSION)
else
    @echo "Tool B will be run..."
    @echo $(VERSION)
endif

# (Never mind the "export". You aren't calling $(MAKE),
# you're just including a makefile.)
TOOL = A
VERSION = IMP-IR5
```

Make gets to the `if` line, `TOOL` has not yet been defined so it evaluates to nothing, so the makefile reads as:

```
ci:
    @echo "Tool B will be run..."
    @echo $(VERSION)

TOOL = A
VERSION = IMP-IR5
```

Mow Make has determined that it will execute the `ci` rule, with `TOOL = A` (too late) and `VERSION = IMP-IR5`. Thus:

```
Tool B will be run...
IMP-IR5
```

Comment: Thanks to you too! But what's weird is that this Master and local were written by someone else, and they had the include up top in the local, and all the exports at the bottom, so that why I followed that. I changed the ordering for just my new TOOL variable like you and @j.w.r. said, and it worked, but all the other exports from before work just fine at the bottom, only my new one fails. Do you know why? =/

Comment: @RaytheonLiszt: I have no idea, but I'm intrigued. Could you pare it down to the smallest makefile that shows this pattern, and append it to your question?

Comment: Ok, added it. I hope you can figure it out :(

Comment: Holy cr@p! Thanks so much! It's so simple, yet I've never seen this explained so well until now. I wish I could mark two answers as accepted! Thanks again!!

Comment: @RaytheonLiszt: "I can live for two months on a good compliment." -- Mark Twain